# JBoss7 + PostgreSQL New missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, persistence, jboss7.x

im migrating a Project from JBoss3 to JBoss7. I just started yesterday and reconfigured my standalone.xml, module.xml and persistence.xml.

In the JBoss modules folder, i created the org/postgres/main dir. In this dir i got the new Postgres JDBC41 Driver and my module.xml.

This is what i get, if i want to start the JBoss:

```
14:42:53,697 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/RESyDS] 

14:42:53,725 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on          http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:42:53,726 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes"   started (with errors) in 3800ms - Started 155 of 234 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies,   76 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Here is my module.xml in /modules/org/postgresql/main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0" name="org.postgresql">  
<resources>  
    <resource-root path="postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar"/>  
</resources>  
<dependencies>  
    <module name="javax.api"/>  
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
</dependencies>  
</module>
```

standalone.xml datasources-part:

```
<datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/RESyDS" pool-name="RESyDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.28.123:5432/dgap</connection-url>
                <driver>postgresql</driver>
                <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                <security>
                    <user-name>resy</user-name>
                    <password>resy</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="em">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/RESyDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have no Idea, how to solve the problem.
Already tried to deploy the driver file, but it doesnt change anything.

I checked all file names, asked my colleagues,im feeling like checked the whole internet for this issue. Nobody knows the hint.

I hope someone can help ;)

Cheers

Comment: hmm, nothing pops out to me as really wrong; the only thing that is not correct is that you have a driver-class inside your datasource, that is part of the driver declaration. Also I don't have the datasources namespace in my driver's module.xml

Comment: Thats it. Seems to work now. Thanks a lot, im a little ashamed now for asking this question ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: What was it exactly? The driver-class or the module namespace?

Comment: Have you tried just deploying the postgresql.jar instead? There isn't really a need to create a module for it. If you're using maven you can use the jboss-as-maven-plugin to configure it https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/add-resource-example.html or just use the web console to deploy then add the datasource.

Comment: @Gimby The driver-class was the reason for not deploying.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Yes, i tried it without success. The reason is described in Gimblys first post.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: BTW, check carefully your connection properties. I came up the same issue when I made a typo in my connection-string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, here's the solution from the comments above:

- Don't include `<driver-class>` in the `<datasource>` node. That belongs to the `<driver>` declaration only. This fixes the error described above
- Don't use `xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0"` in modules/org/postgresql/main/module.xml. That fixes another error which appears when the fist issue is fixed.